# How many hour as a time range are there in given time intervals?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to count hours as a time range in given time intervals. It is a bit difficult for me to put what I want to words in English so let me explain waht I want with an example:

```
  A                 B               C        D          E
1 Start of Fault    End of Fault     Time Ranges        Number of Faults
2 12:00             13:00           00:00    01:00      X
3 12:00             14:00           01:00    02:00      X
4 08:30             23:00           02:00    03:00      X
5 00:00             24:00           03:00    04:00      X
. ...               ...             ...      ...        ...
```

As you can see, I have starting and ending time of a fault. On C and D coloums, I have time ranges starting from 00:00 and ending at 24:00. Also,

```
X = How many faults did happen between a time range (00:00-01:00)?
```

X must scan A and B columns and if a given time range (say 12:00-13:00) is included in any time intervals (say 12:00-13:00, 08:30-23:00), X is the number of intersections between a given time range and time intervals.

I tried to calculate X using this Excel folmula:

```
=IF(AND($A$2>=C2;$B$2<=D2);1;0)+IF(AND($A$3>=C2;$B$3<=D2);1;0)+IF(AND($A$4>=C2;$B$4<=D2);1;0)+IF(AND($A$5>=C2;$B$5<=D2);1;0)
```

But this formula works only if time range and time insterval are equal.

Is there a way for me to get value of X by using an Excel formula?

Thank you in advance.

PS: My native language is not English.

Comment: have a look at `countifs` function..

Comment: A few things aren't clear. 1) are cols A and B independent of cols C and D (A&B = fault data, C&D = summary ranges)?  2) Are you counting events or hours (most rows show multi-hour faults; is that counted as 1 fault regardless of duration)?  3) The faults show overlapping times.  Is each row considered a different fault regardless of the time frames of other faults?  4) Faults span multiple C:D time ranges.  Does a fault get recounted during each C:D period in which it falls (e.g., 4 hr fault counted as 4 faults, 1 in each period)?  (cont'd)

Comment: 5) Is a fault counted if any portion of the fault time falls within the C:D interval, regardless of how short?

Comment: @fixer1234, 1) Yes. 2) I am counting events. 3) Each row is considered a different fault. 4) Yes, a fault is get recounted if it falls in any C:D period. 5) Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&D2,B:B,">="&C2)
```

The only issue with your "Time Range" is that the start and end times *overlap*, meaning some values may be counted twice. To fix this, I chose to use `A<D` but `B>=C`. If this is not your expected behavior and you want them to be counted twice for the same "minute" then you can change `A<D` to `A<=D`.

> [image]

Place the formula in `E2` then fill down.

Comment: your formula is working as expected. Thank you. As you say, start and end times are overlapping. I changed end times like fallows: 00:59, 01:59, 02:59 ...